# what are sufficient approaches for manipulating a list of thousands of individual words

Tags: c++, algorithm, words

I'm trying to design such an application that manipulates a list of thousands of individual words that is stored in a `txt` file for the following tasks,

**1**- Randomly picking up some words.

**2**- Checking whether some entered words by the user are actually in the list.

**3**- Retrieve the entire list from a `txt` file and store it temporarily for subsequent manipulations.

I'm not asking for implementation neither for pseudo codes. I'm looking for sufficient approach to deal with a massive list of words. For the time being, I might go with a vector of strings, however, searching thousands of words will take some times. Of course there must be some strategies to cope with this kind of tasks however, since my background is not Computer Science, I don't know in which direction which I go. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: With any task where the goal is to speed up things, the first thing you need to do is to define use cases in order to measure the actual speed. Then, use a profiler to find bottlenecks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vector of strings is fine for this problem.  Just sort them, and then you can use binary search to find a string in the list.

Answer (score 1):

[Radix trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) are a good solution for searching through word lists for matches. Reduced space for storage, but you'll have to have some custom code for getting and putting words in the list. And the text file won't necessarily be easy to read unless you create the tree anew each time you load from a text file. [Here's an implementation I committed to on GitHub](https://github.com/aardvarkk/cpptrie) (I can't even remember the source material at this point) that might be of assistance to you.